# two inline text boxes aligning properly with other controls using bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have two form controls in one line and other controls properly aligned using Bootstrap v3.3.4

Could you please help me in aligning the top two controls (drop-down and textbox) with the bottom text boxes. 
Thank you in advance

I tried to replicate alignment issue using JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/bswn9o8g/

Also posting the Image here: http://postimg.org/image/4iawvs0zn/
 Here is the HTML code

```
    <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>SearchVM</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.searchBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.searchBy, "Search By", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.TextBox("searchByVal", null, htmlAttributes: new { @placeholder = "SID / PID ", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "First Name", @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MiddleName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MiddleName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Middle Name", @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Last Name", @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Birth Date", @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CauseNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CauseNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Cause#", @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the generated code?

Comment: @Ted: do you mean "View Source" from HTML page?

Comment: The exact nature of your problem is unclear. Please revise your overall question to better explain what the exact behavior you're experiencing is, and what the expected behavior should be. It would also probably behoove you to use the generated code to create a codepen or jsfiddle that replicates the problem and post a link to that in your question. That way we can actually see what your seeing. Short of that, perhaps add a screenshot or two.

Comment: Here is JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/bswn9o8g/

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from your question what do you want to achieve, but i think you want to have your dropdown menu and textbox inline and aligned with the other controls of your form.

Here's what you are looking for :

```
     <div class=" form-group form-inline">
    <div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon">Search by</span>
     <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Search By field i1 required." id="searchBy" name="searchBy">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">SID</option>
    <option value="1">PID</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

and here's the [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/bswn9o8g/2/)

UPDATE:
Here's what's you'r looking for :

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>SearchVM</h4>


        <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-md-5">
                     <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Search By field is required." id="searchBy" name="searchBy"><option selected="selected" value="0">Search By</option>
<option value="1">SID</option>
<option value="2">PID</option>
</select>
      </div>
 <div class="col-md-5">
                        <input class="form-control" id="searchByVal" name="searchByVal" placeholder="SID / PID " type="text" value="" />
      </div>
...
```

And here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mk31u3q1/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Here is the image, shows the expected control alignment: http://postimg.org/image/4iawvs0zn/

Comment: It is not working in my application, even though it is showing in JSFiddle.

Comment: Are you referencing Bootstrap in your application?

Comment: Yes, I am referencing Bootstrap. see the attached pictures
"http://postimg.org/image/7ghsxkmmv/full/"
http://postimg.org/image/ydc9dz1bn/
http://postimg.org/image/8s01e4e43/

Comment: Can you post the code of your rendered html page? 
the compiled one . You can use JSFiddle to share it

Comment: I need the compiled html code. run your application , open your page , right click on the page and choose "View page source" then post that code  on jsfiddle. We need to look at the compiled html file and check stuff

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dpam7ogq/

Complete code, without removing any tags: http://jsfiddle.net/dpam7ogq/1/

Comment: What's in : `Dashboard.css` ? can you remove it for this page? there might be an overlapping of attributes with Bootstrap

Comment: One of your other CSS files are causing the problem. Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hL3uvuks/ importing external `CDN Bootstrap` library and it's working fine.

Comment: I tried to remove the Dashboard.css, but it was not the problem. Still it is not working. Thank you so much for trying to fix the issue. I am not sure, how can I fix the issue...

Comment: remove all other CSS except Bootstrap. it's definitely one of them. Also try a different browser

Comment: Any luck with this issue

Comment: sorry Alundra, no luck. I am trying to redesign the UI, as I am not able to figure out why it is not aligning properly. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: look at you other css files. it's there. start by disbaling all css files except bootstrap and then add one by one

Comment: I tried that immediately after your first suggestion. no luck